# ngx-datatables gives "rxjs_1.fromEvent is not a function" error while sorting

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, ngx-datatable

I'm just following the demo to show a simple datatable. Here is my code:

```html
columns = [
    {name: 'ID', prop: 'id'},
    {name: 'Street Address', prop: 'address.street'},
    {name: 'Suburb', prop: 'address.suburb'},
    {name: 'State', prop: 'address.state'},
    {name: 'Manager Name', prop: 'manager.name'},
    {name: 'Manager Company', prop: 'manager.company'},
  ];
```

```html
<ngx-datatable #table
  class = 'material striped'
  [columns] = "columns"
  [rows] = "rows | async"
  [footerHeight] = "25" >
</ngx-datatable>
```

Sorting does work but, I'm also getting this error when I click on a column to sort the records:

[image]

I get rows as Observable from Firestore.

Comment: Show your RxJS imports.

Comment: `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';` Just this

Comment: Where did you import fromEvent?!

Comment: I never do  it. I'm just using `angularfire2` to get data and store its `snapshot` in an `observable`, which i then pass to rows.

Comment: The Error is in the `DataTableHeaderComponent.html`

Comment: `ngOnInit() {
    this.propertyService
      .valueChnages()
      .subscribe(properties => this.rows = properties);
  }` Just like this.

Comment: Are you using `fromEvent` in your `LongPressDirective`?

Comment: I don't have a `LongPressDirective`. i just copy and pasted the most basic example to create a simple datatable.

Comment: Which version ngx-datatable are you using? I suspect it's 12.0.0 which requires rxjs6

Comment: Yes: "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^12.0.0"

Comment: Should I use rxjs-compat? Or downgrade to an earlier version?

Comment: Try rxjs- compat. I would upgrade angular to version 6

Comment: I'm in a middle of a project, I'm not confident that upgrading would not break by code in terms of comparability with other libraries that I'm  using such as AngularFire2.

Comment: What previous version would you recommend that would work fine with angular 5?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The version of `ngx-datatable` and `rxjs` that you're using are incompatible.

If you're using `ngx-datatable@^12.0.0`, then you need `rxjs@^6.0.0`.

If you can't upgrade `rxjs` (because, for example, you still need to use v5 of Angular), then you can use `ngx-datatable@11.3.2` which works with `rxjs@^5.0.0`.